# Use single or multiple mousecallback for different mouse operations in a single opencv window

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I currently have two mouse callback functions both doing separate things

```
 // Function to choose midpoint of a circle
static void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
{
    //Detect Mouse button event
    if( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
    {
         //store point clicked
    }
}
```

the second callback draws a line from a point clicked on the window whilst the left mouse button is held down to the point at which it's released

```
 // Draws a line from the beginning of a point to another.
 // This line is the diameter of a circle 
 // The first point isn't the coordinates stored by onMouse
static void DrawLine( int event, int x, int y, int, void* ) 
        {
            switch (event)
            {
             case EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
                 // start point
              case EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
                //endpoint
                break;
              case EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
                  if(clicked)
                  {
                    // store point
                  }
                break;
              default    : break;
              }
         }
```

How do I call each function respectively in sequential order. i.e. run onMouse Callback first and the run DrawLine Callback function

```
Main()
{
   setMouseCallback("WinName", onMouse, 0);

   setMouseCallback("WinName", DrawLine, 0);

// capture first frame of video
   cap >> frame;

 // set midpoint when  onMouse is called

 // set coordinates of the line  when DrawLine is called

  while (true)
  {
       cap >> frame;

      // do the rest of your stuff here 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a single callback function `onMouse`:

```
setMouseCallback("WinName", onMouse, 0);
```

You can then call `DrawLine` from `onMouse`:

```
static void DrawLine( int event, int x, int y) 
{
    // Do something...
}

static void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
{
    //Detect Mouse button event
    if( SOME_CONDITION )
    {
         // Do something...
    }
    else
    {
        DrawLine( event, x, y )
    }
}
```

You usually do different things according to modifiers like [CTRL, ALT, SHIFT](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gaab4dc057947f70058c80626c9f1c25ce).

Comment: this was my original idea based on keypresses. I was hoping there'd be an inbuilt opencv function to handle this

Comment: to do what, exactly?

Comment: I've decided to use this method instead. Less messier.